# CSS border properties

Tags: css, border

Is there a better way I can write this CSS border property in one line as `top-left` is `1px` and `right-bottom` are `3px`

```
   border-top: 1px  solid #000;
   border-right: 3px solid #000;
   border-left: 1px  solid #000;
   border-bottom: 3px solid #000;
```

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, when you say:

```
border: 1px solid black;
```

It gets translated this way:

```
border-left-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
border-left-style: solid;
border-left-width: 1px;
border-right-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
border-right-style: solid;
border-right-width: 1px;
border-top-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
border-top-style: solid;
border-top-width: 1px;
```

The first line is called shorthand version.

`border: 1px solid black` is basically shorthanded for `border-color`, `border-width`, `border-style`.
And each of these are also a shorthand.

You can just say it this way:

```
border: solid black;
border-width: 1px 3px 3px 1px;
```

Comment: Thanks 2 lines is better than 4, i just added 3px 1px to the suffix, to get the exact border I wanted

Comment: Indeed only 2 lines are needed, I submitted an edit so your border is in a corner and updated my answer by addind a fourth case

Answer (score 1):

You only can merge top + bottom and left + right (example case `.two`).

You can save 1 line by using `border-color`, `border-style` and `border-width` (the order is top, right, bottom and then left).

You can save 1 additionnal line by merging `border-color` and `border-style` in `border`

```css
.square{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:orange;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}
.one{
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  border-right: 3px solid #000;
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #000;
}
.two{
  border-color: #000;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px 3px;
}
.three{
  border-color: #000;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px 3px 3px 1px;
}
.four{  
  border: #000 solid;
  border-width: 1px 3px 3px 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="square one"></div>
<div class="square two"></div>
<div class="square three"></div>
<div class="square four"></div>
```

Comment: Should be `1px 3px 1px 3px`

Comment: @ParsaArvaneh He asked for 3px on bottom-right, so it's `1px 3px 3px 1px`

Comment: yeah you re right, my bad